# Why do I have to refresh Blocks HTML output / Page blocks HTML every other hour?

Tags: block-cache, magento-1.9.2.0

Whenever I login to magento backend it shows invalidated Block HTML Cache. This is happening even without making a change to the website or database. Why is that and how to fix it?
I am using Magento ver. 1.9.2.0

Comment: You can also check : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8423604/what-does-invalidated-cache-mean-in-magento

Answer (score 1):

Your question is [**already answered in this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8424141/2869218).

I am quoting the vital point below:

> In Magento, whenever you make changes to products, static blocks, etc,
>   it recognizes that the data in the database is no longer the same as
>   what it has in the cache. Unfortunately, Magento doesn't realize **what**
>   cache data is different, just that **something** is different.

You can setup a cron job to refresh cache. Sample code is also available with that thread.

Comment: Well, that's the point, I am getting invalidated block HTML cache even without making any changes to the website/content/design or database. Cron jobs looks like a good idea.

Comment: Each order will reduce stock qty. This marks, ie. stock status block as invalidated. This can also affect category product list. If your settings are to not show out of stock products on category page then listing block might have incorrect data to show.